# Why ther's no display even when i have items react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to build an history page that request data from async storage and display it on the screen

this is my code

```js
function History() {
  let [items, setItems] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("users").then(users => {
      setItems(users.split("*"))
    })
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          <View key = {index} style = {styles.item}>
            <Image
              style={styles.stretch}
              source={require('../assets/logo.png')}
            />
            <Text style={styles.Title}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.number}>+21644987156</Text>
          </View>
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

[there's many items in the async storage and no display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJmSP.jpg)

Comment: Please tag your question with "mind-reading-required".

Comment: You have one error: replace `{items.map((item, index) => {...})}` with `{items.map((item, index) => (...))}`.